# Wamp with php 5.4.9 CURL

Tags: php, curl, wampserver

I have the curl extention enabled:
(php.ini)
`extension=php_curl.dll (UNCHECKED!)`
But when I run this script:

```
if(is_callable('curl_init')){
   echo "Enabled";
}
else
{
   echo "Not enabled";
}
```

it will output: `Not enabled`.
System specs:

- Windows XP, SP3, C++ package 2008.
- php 5.4.9
- Wampserver 5.4

Comment: Check `phpinfo()`, edit the right `php.ini`, restart server. Nobody else has access to your setup/configuration and could possibly tell what's wrong.

Comment: @mario For my phpinfo check this page: [link](http://jmnet.servegame.com/info.php)

Comment: Do you have the extension enabled in the correct `php.ini` file. Use the `wampmanager->Apache->httpd.conf` menu to edit the correct file. The `php.ini` file in `\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.9` is only used by PHP CLI

Comment: Just one point **There is no WAMPServer 5.4** do you mean **2.4**

Comment: Are you using WAMPServer 32bit or 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you can see CURL keywords in your info.php page.[image: see this pic]